# Retrofit Android miss some response from server(not all)

Tags: java, android, django, android-emulator, retrofit2

when I try to send some request in a for loop, log of the server is ok(all request recieved and all responses sent) but in Android Studio Emulator i have only some those responses not all. here My request code

```
 private void updateDatabase(JsonArray arrayJson) {
    final List<JsonObject> user_cars= new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
    for(JsonElement a : arrayJson){
        String carID = a.getAsString();
        carID=carID.substring(0,carID.length()-1);
        int index = carID.lastIndexOf('/');
        Integer id =Integer.parseInt(carID.substring(index+1));
        Log.e("Index",id.toString());
        AdaClient client = ServiceGenerator.createService(AdaClient.class);
        Call<JsonObject> call = client.retrieveCars(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, retrofit2.Response<JsonObject> response) {
                Log.e("user_cars",response.body().toString());
                user_cars.add(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

The request are 7 as you can see in my log id =

```
08-29 12:55:20.497 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/Index: 1
08-29 12:55:20.499 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/Index: 2
08-29 12:55:20.505 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/Index: 3
08-29 12:55:20.506 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/Index: 4
08-29 12:55:20.508 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/Index: 5
08-29 12:55:20.511 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/Index: 8
08-29 12:55:20.512 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/Index: 9
```

Here logcat

```
08-29 12:55:20.748 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/user_cars: {"id":1,"owner":"raul@raul.raul","car":"http://10.10.10.10:8080/cars/60546/","total_km":null,"tires_km":null,"oil_km":null,"breaks_km":null,"engine_km":null,"insurance_date":null,"vehicle_tax_date":null}
08-29 12:55:20.826 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/user_cars: {"id":3,"owner":"raul@raul.raul","car":"http://10.10.10.10:8080/cars/60550/","total_km":null,"tires_km":null,"oil_km":null,"breaks_km":null,"engine_km":null,"insurance_date":null,"vehicle_tax_date":null}
08-29 12:55:20.855 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/user_cars: {"id":4,"owner":"raul@raul.raul","car":"http://10.10.10.10:8080/cars/60551/","total_km":null,"tires_km":null,"oil_km":null,"breaks_km":null,"engine_km":null,"insurance_date":null,"vehicle_tax_date":null}
08-29 12:55:20.863 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/user_cars: {"id":2,"owner":"raul@raul.raul","car":"http://10.10.10.10:8080/cars/60548/","total_km":null,"tires_km":null,"oil_km":null,"breaks_km":null,"engine_km":null,"insurance_date":null,"vehicle_tax_date":null}
08-29 12:55:20.915 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/user_cars: {"id":8,"owner":"raul@raul.raul","car":"http://10.10.10.10:8080/cars/60550/","total_km":null,"tires_km":null,"oil_km":null,"breaks_km":null,"engine_km":null,"insurance_date":null,"vehicle_tax_date":null}
08-29 12:55:20.936 19654-19654/it.uniroma3.adateam.ada E/user_cars: {"id":9,"owner":"raul@raul.raul","car":"http://10.10.10.10:8080/cars/60547/","total_km":null,"tires_km":null,"oil_km":null,"breaks_km":null,"engine_km":null,"insurance_date":null,"vehicle_tax_date":null}
```

Here my server response :

```
[29/Aug/2017 12:55:36] "GET /user-cars/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200                                                                                                                                                    
[29/Aug/2017 12:55:36] "GET /user-cars/3/ HTTP/1.1" 200                                                                                                                                                   
[29/Aug/2017 12:55:36] "GET /user-cars/4/ HTTP/1.1" 200                                                                                                                                                    
[29/Aug/2017 12:55:36] "GET /user-cars/5/ HTTP/1.1" 200                                                                                                                                                    
[29/Aug/2017 12:55:36] "GET /user-cars/2/ HTTP/1.1" 200                                                                                                                                                    
[29/Aug/2017 12:55:36] "GET /user-cars/8/ HTTP/1.1" 200                                                                                                                                                    
[29/Aug/2017 12:55:36] "GET /user-cars/9/ HTTP/1.1" 200
```

As you can see some reponses in logcat is missing the id=5, but is completely random. Why?

Comment: try storing response.body().string in string variable and use that string variable..

Comment: Why no Log.d in onFailure?  How do you know that's not getting called for id 5?

Comment: Just read the log from server and from logcat as you can see logcat miss the car with id 5

Comment: I just noticed that i still have since start this log      E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}

Comment: Do you understand JJF's question?  If you get an error (though the server is indicating 200) you're just ignoring it.  You should log errors, even if that isn't what is going on in this case.

Comment: i understand his question and the log on failure is EOFexception but that is quiet impossible cause server response is complete, and is not an error i think